# UItextField emulate end of text functionality when user writes three or more letters

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have an UIView and inside i have an UITextfield with size of 100 pixels. When the user writes three or more characters i need to emulate the end of text functionality where the user is able to write more letters but all previous characters start disappearing one by one and then if he hits backspace start reappearing one by one. Is this somehow possible using the UITextField delegate?

Comment: Yes. Use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Comment: Is there any example i can find?